# C++: Find bottleneck with memory mapped files

Tags: c++, windows, profiling, memory-mapped-files

I have memory-mapped a file and I get data from it using MemCpy.
Sometimes it is lightening fast, and sometimes surprisingly slow.
For example:
Once 0.15 milliseconds, then the same operation 6 seconds.

I am not sure where the bottleneck is or how to resolve it.

I think I will therefore need to do some rather "deep" analysis to find out what exactely makes the MemCpy operation so slow sometimes.

Can somebody suggest what I should do to track the problem?

Comment: how big is this file? especially compared to your physical memory size and to available free memory

Comment: The file is "only" 250 mb in size. The system is "modern".

Comment: Why not use a profiler to identify where the 6 seconds is being spent ?

Comment: Which profiler exactely do you mean, please?

Comment: if your disk is 40 MB/s (typical for laptop drive), it will have to spend 6 seconds to read your file into memory

Comment: But wouldn't that happen only once?

Comment: it depends on vm subsystem and memory usage. OS may decide to throw cached file away and read it again

Comment: `Which profiler exactely do you mean, please?`. Do you have Windows Performance Analyzer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448170.aspx ?

Comment: A question: When I use MemCpy on the mapped file, ProcMon tells me that the operation is "ReadFile". Can that be?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to use

- [VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

  > Locks the specified region of the process's virtual address space into physical memory, ensuring that subsequent access to the region will not incur a page fault.
- [VirtualUnlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There's a background page **[Working with Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** that lists and describes more relevant API calls.

Comment: I have used MapVirtual file and received void*                   m_pVoiceData; How would I lock that, please?